# occasional bursts of blind

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "occasional bursts of blind" in this example mean?

> Rosseau, too, must have reinforced the coarse-grained, rough peasant in Tolstoy with his strongly moralistic, puritanical strain, his suspicion of, and antipathy to the rich, the powerful, the happy as such, his streak of genuine vandalism, **and occasional bursts of blind**, very Russian rage against Western sophistication and refinement, and that adulation of 'virtue' and simple tastes, of the 'healthy' moral life, the militant, anti-liberal barbarism, which is one of Rousseau's specific contributions to the stock of Jacobin ideas.

I've searched that in many dictionaries and haven't found a clear answer.

Is this a phrase or expression?

Comment: "*Butsts*" ? Is there a word like that ? Did you mean *'Bursts'* ?

Comment: I am very sorry. You are right. that was "bursts".

Comment: This is a very strange phrase, could you add a little more content after the phrase ? Maybe it is a "burst of blind something", like "blind rage" or something. Maybe then it'll make sense :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> occasional bursts of blind, {very Russian} rage against Western sophistication

The expression is *blind rage*, *very Russian* is a qualifier inserted between "blind" and "rage", acting as second adjective.

The rage is both "blind" and "very Russian".

A completely different (random) example:

> a serving of a sweet, chocolate-laden desert

Comment: I really appreciate your help.

Comment: +1 In AmE, we like to say "chocolatey".  It's a partial rhyme with "malady".